# Is it okay to create a tag for a specific class of problem?

Tags: discussion, tags, related-problems

I've recently noticed 4 different questions that come down to "I've noticed that I get full speed from my Linksys Wi-Fi AP right after I reboot/reset/reconfigure it, but after a few minutes it goes back to being slow". I don't know if they're all going to come down to the same root cause, so I don't want to mark them as exact duplicates of each other. But to keep them all related to each other, I was considering creating a tag like "linksys-slowdown" and tagging them all with it.

Would that be an acceptable way to go? It seems like most tags are the names of certain technologies or products, and I don't recall seeing tags for certain classes of problems, so I thought I'd ask.

For the curious:
[odd wifi speed issue - after reset runs at 10mb+, after 5 minutes back to 0.5mb](https://superuser.com/questions/423299/odd-wifi-speed-issue-after-reset-runs-at-10mb-after-5-minutes-back-to-0-5mb)
[Wireless from 54mbps to 1mbps](https://superuser.com/questions/107784/wireless-from-54mbps-to-1mbps)
[Slow connection on WRT160N or WRT54G](https://superuser.com/questions/416513/slow-connection-on-wrt160n-or-wrt54g)
[How can I make wireless transfers faster on a Linksys WRT54G running DD-WRT?](https://superuser.com/questions/399902/how-can-i-make-wireless-transfers-faster-on-a-linksys-wrt54g-running-dd-wrt/399979#399979)

Comment: Why exactly don't you want to mark them as dupes?

Comment: @nhinkle I don't know that they're exact duplicates. They have different speed differences listed, different AP models in some cases, different firmware distros in some cases. It could end up being that they have different root causes and thus different solutions.

Comment: As it turns out, the first one I listed "odd wifi speed issue..." isn't a Linksys box, it's a 2Wire box. So these are even less likely to all come down to the same root cause.

Comment: Well, using a tag to relate some similar problems sounds suspiciously like a meta tag. Do they show up  the "related" bar for each other? If they're correctly tagged (things like wifi, networking, etc.) then they should be easy enough to find. Routers slow down sometimes. I don't think we need a whole class of tags for it. That's like a "problem" or "uh-oh" tag.